# Как из NodeJs по HTTP запросам передавать данные в Python файл

Tags: python, node.js, http, flask

Я хочу сделать бота в майнкрафте и бота в дискорде так, чтобы через бота в дискорде можно было бы отправлять сообщения на сервер в майнкрафте.

Python

```py
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

activity = disnake.Activity(
    name = f"на мир",
    type = disnake.ActivityType.watching,
)

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/', intents = disnake.Intents.all(), activity = activity)
@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = bot.get_channel(ID)
    if MessageNodeJS:
        await channel.send(MessageNodeJS) # Это сообщение которое мы получили из NodeJs
@Bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == ID:
        # ПЕРЕДАЕМ message.content в NodeJS
Bot.run('token')
```

NodeJs

```js
const mineflayer = require("mineflayer");
const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 25565,
    version: "1.12.2",
    username: "BotName"
});

bot.on('message', (jsonMsg) => {
    let MessageNodeJS = jsonMsg.toString() # Это мы должны отправить на python
}
bot.on('spawn', () => {
    bot.chat(message.content); # Тут мы получаем сообщение отправленое в чате
});
```

Comment: Полагаю, что посредством сокета

Comment: ну я это понимаю, но сам код не могу написать